# Azure B2C Custom Policy with Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

**Context**:
I've been working with Azure IEF for a while and I manage to create and deploy my Custom Policies using azure portal. Currently I'm trying to use gitlab pipelines to upload my custom policies automatically.

**Problem**:
I'm trying to use az rest to make graph calls in my ci/cd file. I couldn't find Azure documentation about this feature for the v1 graph version. Also, my beta graph calls are failing because the entity only allows JSON format body but beta documentation specifies that content-type must be XML.
In any case, beta is not recommended for prod env so it's not an option for me.

**Question**:
Is there any possible way to achieve this kind of automation? I'm kind of stuck and MS documentation seems a bit misleading.